# Как передать узнать абсолютный путь к файлу в OnModelCreating в dbContext?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2, entity-framework-core-2

Я делаю начальную инициализацию данных (Seed) в новом стиле Entity Framework Core 2.1

То есть логика инициализации идёт в классе `ApplicationDbContext` в функции:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
```

Но моя инициализация идёт на основании JSON файлов, то есть мне нужно прочитать эти файлы, а для этого нужен доступ к текущему пути.

Раньше это получал из `IHostingEnvironment` взятый из комплектного Di контейнера ASP.NET Core ,  но откуда его теперь взять в функции `OnModelCreating`?

В сам конструктор `ApplicationDbContext` передавать `IHostingEnvironment`, было бы плохим решением (да и не факт что получится), так как это основной класс работы с данными и в нём явно не нужна лишняя переменная, притом что она бы использовалась только один раз при создании.

Answer (score 1):

Такое решение я выбрал на данный момент.

Превращаем красивый и изолированный Di паттерн в ASP.NET Core 2.1 в классический статический Di контейнер.

В файле `program.cs`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    DiContainer.ServiceProvider = webHost.Services;
    webHost.Run();
}
```

Класс `DiContainer`

```
public static class DiContainer
{
    private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider {
        get => _serviceProvider;
        set
        {
            if (_serviceProvider == null)
            {
                _serviceProvider = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not set static ServiceProvider two times");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В коде получаем любой сервис так:

```
IHostingEnvironment env = DiContainer.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
```

Возможно решение покажется вам некрасивым, но что тут можно сказать, за неимением лучшего, используем лучшее из того что есть.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений это использовать внутри `Path.GetFullPath`, который возвращает абсолютный путь относительно сборки, и для него не нужен Dependancy Injection.

Но это больше похоже на хак, хочется узнать легальное решение.